# How to show SystemUI on secondary display?

Tags: android, android-source

I've built AOSP emulator and added secondary display (it has displayId = 2). It worked fine and I'm able to start activities on it with:

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.project/.MyActivity --display 2
```

However, this secondary display is just empty. It doesn't have notifaction bar, navigation buttons etc. It's just a black screen and although starting apps works fine I'm more interested in showing SystemUI components there, so could someone give me a hint how to show SystemUI on secondary display?

Comment: Have you seen: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/system-decorations

Comment: Yes, I've tried setShouldShowSystemDecorsLocked, I've verified via dumpsys that my display has "FLAG_SHOULD_SHOW_SYSTEM_DECORATIONS" etc. I even tried "force desktop mode" developer option as described here: https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/testing-dev-environment but still SystemUI doesn't show up.

Comment: And you've confirmed that your Launcher is configured correctly? https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/multi_display/system-decorations#launcher i.e. you are using the example in `platform/development/samples/MultiDisplay`

Comment: I'm not sure if my Launcher is correct. Maybe it's worth mentioning that I'm building car emulator, not phone emulator and I've created the secondary display using hw.display1 in config.ini. As to the launcher I'm using the default one which for car is packages/apps/Car/Launcher and it doesn't support SECONDARY_HOME, so later I've modified this project and added my activity for handling SECONDARY_HOME and indeed it's launched (see purple screen on the right) -> https://i.imgur.com/aJnZjyt.png but still no SystemUI there, only my activity.